# Detach from docker run from script without killing container

Tags: bash, emacs, docker, nohup

I have a script which contains this line:

```
fgrep -m 1 'PostgreSQL init process complete' <( docker run --name test-postgres-migration \
                                                            -a STDOUT -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.4 )
```

However, even if I change it to:

```
fgrep -m 1 'PostgreSQL init process complete' <( docker run --name test-postgres-migration \
                                                            -a STDOUT -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.4 </dev/null )
```

or:

```
fgrep -m 1 'PostgreSQL init process complete' <( docker run --name test-postgres-migration \
                                                            -a STDOUT -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.4 </dev/null ) </dev/null
```

or even when I put the entire line in a separate shell script and wrap it in `nohup`:

```
nohup ./boot-container.sh
```

the docker container still dies if the script is killed (by emacs) when it is on a later line. This happens because the docker client command is still running, and even though it has PID 1 as its parent, for some mysterious reason (maybe due to a shared <strike>stdin file handle</strike> <strike>or tty</strike>) it gets killed too when the script gets killed, which in turn causes the docker container it has started to die. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, even `nohup` isn't sufficient - it's necessary to use `setsid`:

```
fgrep -m 1 'PostgreSQL init process complete' <( setsid docker run --name test-postgres-migration \
                                                                   -a STDOUT -p 5432:5432 postgres:9.4 )
```

This solves my problem on Linux - I haven't verified whether the problem occurs on Mac or Unixes, or if [this unofficial port of setsid](https://github.com/jerrykuch/ersatz-setsid) to Mac and other Unixes fixes it.